# Where's the giant baby head from?

Tags: phineas-and-ferb

There's this giant disembodied baby human head that shows up in lots of episodes of *Phineas and Ferb*.  It never does anything, it never seems to have any story significance, it's not even funny.  It just appears for less than a second, then it's gone.

What's the deal with that?  Does the giant head have a back story, whether in universe or out of universe?

Here's a screenshot of the head from "Rollercoaster - The Musical":

[image: Screenshot showing the head from "Rollercoaster - The Musical"]

Comment: http://phineasandferb.wikia.com/wiki/Giant_Floating_Baby_Head

Comment: **One last question: What is with the giant floating baby head? (It's shown up in several episodes). We like it a lot when Candace says, "What does that even mean?"**

**Povenmire:** *That came from one board panel drawn by Mike Diederich and one of our directors, Rob Hughes thought it was hilarious and made a whole bit about it. Now it shows up all the time.*

**Marsh:** ***We try not to think too much about the floating baby head . . . It makes us laugh, 'nuff said***. - http://www.tampabay.com/features/parenting/quick-wit-funny-characters-drive-phineas-and-ferb/993119

Comment: On teh sidenote answer is nobody know, even Phineas and Ferb don't know

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Beginning at the [wiki](https://phineasandferb.fandom.com/wiki/Giant_Floating_Baby_Head#Background_Information), which, while not a reliable source by itself actually provides a source:

> The giant baby head came, according to Dan Povenmire, "one board panel drawn by Mike Diederich and one of our directors, Rob Hughes thought it was hilarious and made a whole bit about it. Now it shows up all the time."<sup>[[1](http://www.tampabay.com/features/parenting/article993119.ece)]</sup>

This link goes to [a page on tampabay.com](http://www.tampabay.com/features/parenting/article993119.ece), which unfortunately leads to a 404 now. However, contrary to what @JohnP said in their answer, I was able to find the link on the Web Archive, at [a crawl in 2009](http://web.archive.org/web/20091006022432/http://www.tampabay.com/features/parenting/article993119.ece).

The relevant portion:

> **One last question: What is with the giant floating baby head? (It's shown up in several episodes). We like it a lot when Candace says, "What does that even mean?"**
>
> Povenmire: That came from one board panel drawn by Mike Diederich and one of our directors, Rob Hughes thought it was hilarious and made a whole bit about it. Now it shows up all the time.
>
> Marsh: We try not to think too much about the floating baby head . . . It makes us laugh, 'nuff said.

---

In universe, nobody knows exactly where it's from. The [wiki](https://phineasandferb.fandom.com/wiki/One_Good_Scare_Ought_to_Do_It!/Transcript) is actually very helpful and provides a transcript of the entire episode, for *every* episode as far as I can tell:

> [image: cartoonish baby head]
>
> **Candace**: Phineas! When Mom sees that you've built a haunted house in the backyard with werewolves and vampires and a Giant Floating Baby Head? What's that even about?
>   [...]
>   **Phineas**: That was a great day, Ferb. What did you think the scariest thing was?
>   **Ferb**: Definitely the Giant Floating Baby Head.
>   **Phineas**: Yeah...
>   *(The ending of the Phineas and Ferb Theme plays.)*
>   **Phineas**: Yeah, where did that come from?! *(Ferb shrugs)* Hm.
>   *(The theme continues.)*
>   <sub>"[One Good Scare Ought To Do It!](https://phineasandferb.fandom.com/wiki/One_Good_Scare_Ought_to_Do_It!/Transcript)"</sub>

> [image: two cartoon characters singing]
>
> **Phineas**: We spent a day fighting pharmaceutical zombies,
>   Would've solved cold-fusion but did fashion instead.
>   We met Klimpaloon and Meap and the Lake Nose Monster
>   **Phineas, Candace, and Ferb:** But we're still baffled by the Giant Floating Baby Head.
>   <sub>"[Last Day Of Summer](https://phineasandferb.fandom.com/wiki/Last_Day_of_Summer/Transcript)"</sub>

---

My personal theory, though, is that the baby head came from another dimension. We see a whole dimension of baby heads when Phineas, Ferb, Dr. Doofenshmirtz, Perry, Candace, and a whole bunch of evil robots are dimension hopping. At 0:50 in [this video](https://youtu.be/uQP7n8LjstA?t=50s), we can see a whole bunch of similar baby heads:

[image: lots of cartoon baby heads, psychedelic-looking background]

So it would seem that the baby heads came from another dimension and somehow ended up in our normal dimension, or it's somehow magically attracted to Phineas & Ferb's projects... anyway, it appears to come from the baby head dimension.

Answer (score 0):

It appears the Tampa Bay link given in the comments has decayed, (and is not available on archive.org that I can find), however the [Phineas and Ferb wiki](https://phineasandferb.fandom.com/wiki/Giant_Floating_Baby_Head) has the pertinent part cited as part of the background (Credit to Valorum for original links)

> The giant baby head came, according to Dan Povenmire, "one board panel drawn by Mike Diederich and one of our directors, Rob Hughes thought it was hilarious and made a whole bit about it. Now it shows up all the time."[1](https://phineasandferb.fandom.com/wiki/Giant_Floating_Baby_Head)

So basically it was a gag that a director thought was hilarious and it stuck. The wiki also has other appearances by said head.

Comment: I was originally just going to edit your answer to include the information I dug up from the Wayback Machine, but I ended up posting [my own answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/175108/33591), because you didn't provide any in-universe information. ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score 0):

The Floating Baby Head was originally created by Steve Willis and appeared in the nationally distributed comic Bezango Obscuro in 1994.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  This is interesting information; do you have any references/images of it?  It would be great if we could see it to compare.